# Can you suggest any good word, phrase, quote of the day resources?

Tags: ressources

Can you suggest any blogs, email subscriptions, twitter feeds etc. of French words, phrases, or quotes of the day?

I'm looking for something that will present me daily with a single random word/phrase/quote. It could be an email or a twitter feed (or some similar asynchronous presentation). For example, in English there's a site called [A Word A Day](https://wordsmith.org/words/today.html). You can visit to get a word, or you can subscribe to get an email of that word. I'm looking for something similar but for French.

For example, does the Larousse or Petit Robert on-line have subscription services?

If you can, please give links and your assessment of the words/phrases.

Any and all kinds are welcome. Famous quotes from authors, vocabulary for school children, slang expressions, whatever.

Also any medium is OK. Twitter feed, email, whatever (even paper mail, but online is best).

Answer (score 1):

[Expressio.fr](https://www.expressio.fr/?utm_source=newsletter&utm_medium=mail&utm_campaign=daily) is a really great daily email of non-literal expressions that come with a short history and explanation.

Answer (score 1):

*Le Monde*, *"journal français de référence"*, is proposing [such a service](https://dicocitations.lemonde.fr/abonnementcitationdujour.php), but there's no explanations inside the email, just the quote and the source.

Comment: For quotes, I think that is sufficient. For a word of the day though it's nice to have some extra history or relevance.